Difference between .pt and .pth extensions in PyTorch model saving
I'm working on developing models using PyTorch and frequently experiment with pre-trained models. 've read through the PyTorch documentation.
When saving models, I've noticed that sometimes the files have a .pt extension and other times a .pth extension. Is there a difference between these two, and if so, what is it?

There is no functional difference between .pt and .pth when saving PyTorch models. Both extensions are commonly used, and PyTorch can load either one without issue.
PyTorch's torch.save() function doesn't care about the extension. You can use .pt, .pth, or even something else (though it's not recommended).
In the early days of PyTorch, .pth was more prevalent. However, .pth files can also be used for Python path configuration, leading to potential confusion. To avoid this ambiguity, the PyTorch community favors the .pt extension for model checkpoints.
